# Mirror shape keys does not work

Tags: modeling, mirror, shape-keys

I'm trying to model a bird following a tutorial and I'm freezed on the shape keys tool. I would like to mirror the left eyelid so that I can open the right one using the secret entry `mirror shape keys` but the problem is that it doesn't work. The right eyelid doesn't open. Infact it says that `1 vertices mirrored,12075 vertices failed`. Do you have any suggestion to give me why it does not work ? thanks. As usually you can check the attached screenshots to better understand the problem.

[image: my bird]

[image: tutorial picture 1]

[image: tutorial picture 2]

Comment: Your blender is too old. Make sure you always use the latest version. Maybe that'll fix.

Comment: I'm using blender 2.76b. The version of blender used on the tutorial is too old,not mine.

Comment: So download the version on tutorial and open your *.blend file, if that worked, report a bug to developers, if still not working, then maybe you did something wrong.

Comment: I have tried to follow this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nlf959QT9VI ; he used blender 2.73. It did not work cause the same error : 1 vertices mirrored and 12075 vertices failed.

Comment: maybe I found the solution by deleting half of the bird's body and then applying the mirror modifier...

Comment: You really didn't do that? O_o